# Админ панель перекрывает меню

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит? Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-sticky-headers-wordpress-admin-bar-behave/

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо добавить следующий код в CSS-файл:

```
body.admin-bar #branding-wrap {top: 28px;} 
body.admin-bar #wrapper {margin-top: 145px;}
```

- класс `body.admin` позволит убедиться, что эти стили применятся только в случае, когда админ-панель видна.

Источник решения: [Admin bar and fixed header issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/36923)

Comment: Не помогло, но проблему решил (добавил ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Это перенесёт админ панель в нижнюю часть страницы сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вставляем следующий код в functions.php
Если раскомментировать одну строчку кода, перенос админ панели вниз страницы сработает также и в админке сайта.

```php
// Отключение стандартных CSS в HTML-коде
function my_filter_head()
{
    remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}

add_action('get_header', 'my_filter_head');

// CSS для прилепления админки к нижнему краю страницы
function true_move_admin_bar()
{
    echo '
    <style type="text/css">
    html{margin-bottom:32px !important}
    * html body{margin-bottom:32px !important}
    #wpadminbar{top:auto !important;bottom:0}
    #wpadminbar .menupop .ab-sub-wrapper{bottom:32px;-moz-box-shadow:2px -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-webkit-box-shadow:2px -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:2px -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}
    @media screen and ( max-width:782px ){
        html{margin-bottom:46px !important}
        * html body{margin-bottom:46px !important}
        #wpadminbar{position:fixed}
        #wpadminbar .menupop .ab-sub-wrapper{bottom:46px}
    }
    </style>
    ';
}

//add_action( 'admin_head', 'true_move_admin_bar' ); // в админке
add_action('wp_head', 'true_move_admin_bar'); // на сайте
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот что я придумал )

Добавил над шапкой:

```
<?php
if ( is_admin_bar_showing() ) {
    ?>
    <div style="height:32px"></div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Легче всего решить скриптом по типу этого

```
if ($('#wpadminbar'))
        $('.your-header').css('margin-top', '32px')
```

Или можно добавить инлайн стили к хедеру в html

```
<header class="your-header" <?php if ( is_admin_bar_showing() ) { ?> style="margin-top: 32px" <?php } ?>>
```